# Client denied by server configuration - IP listed is server's own IP

Tags: php, apache-2.4

Something odd is happening on my server. The Apache log shows lots of requests *from the server's own IP address*. I do *not* suspect the server is compromised. I suspect some PHP code is malfunctioning but I don't know how to trace it.

I had to block the server from itself in htaccess because too many sessions were being generated, but the requests are still occurring and resulting in access denied errors.

I need to find out what is generating the requests. Below I have pasted a 4 lines from the Apache error log, ***all of which were generated within the same exact second*** (of a total of 24 generated in that second!). I suspect that somewhere in a PHP script there is something causing this. How can I find out the source of these requests?

*Note that the IP that shows up is not the localhost IP, but the server's external IP. That may be significant.*

```
[Mon Sep 21 17:35:21.056244 2015] [access_compat:error] [pid 13385] [client 64.123.123.123:44407] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/user1/public_html/403.shtml
[Mon Sep 21 17:35:21.065225 2015] [access_compat:error] [pid 13406] [client 64.123.123.123:44408] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/user1/public_html/image/catalog/somepath/ABC-1234XYZ.jpg
[Mon Sep 21 17:35:21.065270 2015] [access_compat:error] [pid 13406] [client 64.123.123.123:44408] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/user1/public_html/403.shtml
[Mon Sep 21 17:35:21.066066 2015] [access_compat:error] [pid 13155] [client 64.123.123.123:44409] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/user1/public_html/image/catalog/someotherpath/DEF-AAA999Z.jpg
```

By the way, since August 23rd there are 535,263 lines in my Apache error log where my own server's IP is the client. This is a huge problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: @mfinni please explain why you think the server is "compromised". As far as I know it is suffering from some sloppy coding, but if it is compromised I would certainly like to know.

Comment: man, you should at least take a look at your apache's access logs.

Comment: @drookie I don't see anything in the access logs that matches. E.g. I have 8 errors at `Thu Sep 24 13:57:43` in the `error_log` but the access log has nothing during that second. The closest it has are 2 lines at 32 seconds: `::1 - - [24/Sep/2015:13:57:32 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -`